# Mapping Formula in fluent nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, formula, lazy-loading

Im having a entity called Event:

```
 public virtual int ID { get;set;}
 public virtual string Name { get;set;}
 public virtual Event Master { get;set;}
 public virtual int ChildrenCount { get;set;}
```

The Childrencount is mapped :

```
   Map(x => x.ChildrenCount).LazyLoad().Formula("(Select count(*) from Events Where Events.Master_id=Event_id)");
```

Sometimes i want to now the value of ChildrenCount and i set the Fetchmode to Eager

```
   store.SetFetchMode("ChildrenCount",NHibernate.FetchMode.Eager);
```

But the system still lazyloads.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "fetch all properties" hint in HQL:

```
from Event fetch all properties
```

That will load all your lazy properties.

Comment: Im not sure that solves the problem. By now i solved it bit creating a list<event> and then iterating through it to perform a select count on each. I only wonders why store.SetFetchMode("ChildrenCount",NHibernate.FetchMode.Eager); doesnt have any effect

Comment: I think it solves exactly the problem you are describing. SetFetchMode is used for collection association not for Lazy properties as your ChildrenCount is. But sounds like you could solve your problem in a number of ways, for instance by using a Projection instead.